# Get Record of the given month in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like :

```
id     trans_date                  resp_code 
------------------------------------------------
1      2011-02-15 12:47:09    1 
2      2011-02-24 12:47:09    1
3      2011-02-29 12:47:09    1
4      2011-03-11 12:47:09    1
5      2011-03-15 12:47:09    1
6      2011-03-22 12:47:09    1
7      2011-04-10 12:47:09    1
8      2011-04-11 12:47:09    1
```

All I want is to fetch all the records of the given `month`.
Like For the `month March[03], I should get row 4,5, and 6`.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
 WHERE trans_date BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND DATE_ADD('2011-03-01', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

You could also follow this query

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
 WHERE MONTH(trans_date) = 3
   AND YEAR(trans_date) = 2011
```

but it will cause fullscan thus will be slow on large amount of data

Answer (score 3):

You could use MySQL's [MONTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE MONTH( trans_date ) = 3
```

Comment: this is quite slow on large datasets